# How get value matching multiple column value of MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to match the multiple same column value of MySQL table using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my table below.

**db_user:**

```
id      status    book_id

 1        0         22

 2        0         22

 3        1         22

 4        0         23
```

Here I need the `select query` and condition is if `status=0` for same `book_id` means if table has lets say `book_id=22 and all status=0` then only it will return value true otherwise false. I am writing one example below.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_user where status=0 and....");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
   $data=$row['book_id'];
}else{
   return 0;
}
```

Here as per the example table only last row will fetch because for `book_id=22` there is `status=1` present. The data will only fetch when for one `book_id` all status=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses aggregation to check the status values:

```
SELECT book_id
FROM db_user
GROUP BY book_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

We can also use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.book_id
FROM db_user t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM db_user t2
                  WHERE t1.book_id = t2.book_id AND t2.status <> 0);
```

Comment: Nobody does 'old school' anymore :-(

Comment: @Strawberry I knew that was you just by the first few words of the comment.  It had your "flavour."

Comment: Its throwing error `#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'easyride.db_user.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @subhra Nope.  My queries can't result in that error, you're running something else (perhaps a modification of what I wrote).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : your second query is working but its fetching multiple value means if all `status=0` then also its fetching book_id=22 multiple times.

Comment: @subhra Good catch.  Use `SELECT DISTINCT` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a not in for the id with status 1

```
select * 
from my_table 
where book_id not in (
 select book_id 
 from my_table 
 where status = 1  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, we would have solved it this way. I say, if it ain't broke, don't fix it...

```
 SELECT DISTINCT x.*
            FROM my_table x
            LEFT 
            JOIN my_table y
              ON y.book_id = x.book_id
             AND y.status = 1
           WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

its very simple:

`SELECT book_id,MAX(status) max_status FROM db_user GROUP BY book_id`

is `max_status` is 0 then all is 0 no larger than that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below query.

```
select * from db_user where status=0 and book_id not in (select book_id from db_user where status = 1 );
```

I have tested it and it works.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of an existing answer

Comment: Please look closely the query is different, I have added status=0 in the query and checked in my pc if its working or not. @Strawberry